# I am trying to implement permissions in asp.net boilerplate and I can't seem to get it right

Tags: asp.net-boilerplate, abp

I am getting the error message:

> Required permissions are not granted. At least one of these permissions must be granted: [Plug entity]

Please also advice on how to grant the permissions.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Sprint.Plug
{
    [AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_PlugEntity)]
    public class PlugAppService: AsyncCrudAppService<PlugEntity, PlugDto, Guid>, IPlugAppService
    {        
        public PlugAppService(IRepository<PlugEntity,Guid> repository):base(repository)
        {

        }        
    }
}

namespace Sprint.Authorization
{
    public static class PermissionNames
    {
        public const string Pages_Tenants = "Pages.Tenants";

        public const string Pages_Users = "Pages.Users";

        public const string Pages_Roles = "Pages.Roles";

        public const string Pages_PlugEntity = "Pages.PlugEntity";
    }
}

namespace Sprint.Authorization
{
    public class SprintAuthorizationProvider : AuthorizationProvider
    {
        public override void SetPermissions(IPermissionDefinitionContext context)
        {
            context.CreatePermission(PermissionNames.Pages_Users, L("Users"));
            context.CreatePermission(PermissionNames.Pages_Roles, L("Roles"));
            context.CreatePermission(PermissionNames.Pages_Tenants, L("Tenants"), multiTenancySides: MultiTenancySides.Host);
            context.CreatePermission(PermissionNames.Pages_PlugEntity, L("PlugEntity"), multiTenancySides: MultiTenancySides.Tenant);
        }

        private static ILocalizableString L(string name)
        {
            return new LocalizableString(name, SprintConsts.LocalizationSourceName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you add new permission you need also create relationship in AbpPermissions table. Also if you like have localization in your error message, you need add record in coresponding .xml file.

Comment: Do you mind to show step-by-step procedure? for creating the relationship